# Measure number of events in the past X minutes/hours

Tags: java, timer, histogram, metrics

I am using `Codahale Metrics` in my application and I would like to know if there is any way to measure the number of events in the past X minutes/hours. I know that a `Timer` provides a one, five and fifteen minute rate but I am looking for the total count in a window of time.

Also, I have tried using a `Histogram` with a `SlidingWindowReservoir` but it doesn't expose the functionality I am looking for. It exposes percentile information.

Is there any way to achieve this using `Codahale Metrics`? If not, is it there a way to extend it to support this? If not, any other good library to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use histogram of SlidingTimeWindowReservoir:

```
offersMinuteHistogram = new SlidingTimeWindowReservoir(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

offersMinuteHistogram.getSnapshot().getValues().length
```

This lenght is number of updates of histogram at last minute.

Comment: I was also looking for something similar. Thanks for your answer.